# I am trying to download Ubuntu to use in VirtualBox but every time I try to download it, it fails?

Tags: windows, downloads

I have tried downloading Ubuntu many times just to have the download fail about halfway through. Any help?

Comment: Try to download it via torrent. The speed will be greater and you can pause anytime. Even in case your internet connection fails, the torrent will continue at the percentage you left it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try snagging a copy from a mirror listed at the bottom of this page - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading via torrent or a mirror link:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads